# Forward logs to Index Template in stead of directly to Index from Fluent-bit to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluent-bit

I´m using Fluent-bit (`v1.3.7`) with output to ElasticSearch. Is it possible to configure Fluent-bit to use the **Elastic Index Template** name in stead of default **Index Name** in the output plugin configuration?

Reason for this is that I don't want Fluent-bit creating new Index every day, but rather lean on the **Index Lifecyle Policies** in ElasticSearch, where rollover configurations are defined.

Looking at the plugin [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.3/output/elasticsearch) it only provides support for setting `Logstash_Prefix` and `Logstash_DateFormat`, which leads to something like this `logstash-2020.04.07` where the **Index Template name** would be something like this `logstash`

Comment: It has been a lot of time since you asked this, have you figured this out? I am facing a similar issue